# python 2.7 os.path.isdir(unicode abspath string) returns nothing

Tags: python, unicode, directory

I am trying to find folders in `os.listdir` output. But, `os.path.isdir` returns nothing about that directory named `u'\u0130letildi'` in `self.file_list` when faces with unicode directory in that list. So I can't pop that directory from listdir.

Sample code is working with ipython console, but my project.

```
import os
a = os.path.expanduser(u"~")  # this creates unicode absolute user path var.
b = "Documents\\Gelen Fax"    # this is the base folder that I try to use files in it
c = os.path.join(a, b)        # output is: u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax'
l = os.listdir(c)
# can print list of the unicode file names:
# [u'02163595310_20141114_001406.pdf',
#  u'Thumbs.db',
#  u'Yedek',
#  u'\u0130letildi']
```

That last object in list is giving headaches since couple of days.

```
for x in l:
    print(type(os.path.join(c,x)), os.path.join(c,x), os.path.isdir(os.path.join(c,x)))

(<type 'unicode'>, u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\02163595310_20141114_001406.pdf', False)
(<type 'unicode'>, u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\Thumbs.db', False)
(<type 'unicode'>, u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\Yedek', True)
(<type 'unicode'>, u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\\u0130letildi', True)
```

so far everything is normal, but when I put it in my project it starts failing. When I call `GetFileList().filtered_list()` there is no trace of the folder `u'\u0130letildi'` while running `exclude_directories()` method. But, it's availabe in `self.file_list` arrived to:

```
log.debug(self.file_list)
for f in self.file_list:
    log.debug("%s - %s - %s" % (repr(type(f)), repr(f), repr(os.path.isdir(f))))
    if os.path.isdir(f):
         self.file_list.pop(self.file_list.index(f))
```

Output of the log above is:

```
[u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\02163595310_20141114_001406.pdf', u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\Thumbs.db', u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\Yedek', u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\\u0130letildi']

<type 'unicode'> - u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\02163595310_20141114_001406.pdf' - False
<type 'unicode'> - u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\Thumbs.db' - False
<type 'unicode'> - u'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Gelen Fax\\Yedek' - True
```

As you can see above, the `u'\u0130letildi'` directory is available in list log. But there is no trace when the list iterated in for loop.

Here is my classes:

```
class FSTools():
    """
    File System Tools Class
    create_directory: Creates directory in given path
    control_directory: Checks directory existence in given path
    safe_make_directory: Cehcks directory existence before make
    user_path: Returns current user home directory path
    target_dir_path: Returns given target directory full path under current user
    """
    def __init__(self, directory=None):
        if directory is None:
            raise Exception(u"No directory name or path given.")
        self.directory = directory

    @property
    def user_path(self):
        return os.path.expanduser(u"~")

    def target_dir_path(self):
        return os.path.join(self.user_path, self.directory)

    def make_directory(self):
        created = False
        try:
            os.makedirs(self.target_dir_path())
            created = True
        except Exception as e:
            log.exception(e.message)
        finally:
            return created

    def check_directory(self):
        return os.path.exists(self.target_dir_path())

    def safe_make_directory(self):
        if not self.check_directory():
            if not self.make_directory():
                raise Exception(u"Unable to create directory: <<{directory}>>".format(directory=self.directory))
            else:
                log.info(u"Directory created: <<{directory}>>".format(directory=self.directory))
        else:
            log.warning(u"Directory exsists: <<{directory}>>".format(directory=self.directory))

class GetFileList():
    """
    Returns files list in given target directory
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.fstools = FSTools(SETTINGS["target_directory"])
        self.target_dir = self.fstools.target_dir_path()
        log.info("Getting file list in {target}".format(target=self.target_dir))
        self.file_list = os.listdir(self.target_dir)
        self.file_list = [os.path.join(self.target_dir, f) for f in self.file_list]
        self.exclude_directories()
        self.exclude_files()

    def exclude_directories(self):
        try:
            log.debug(self.file_list)
            for f in self.file_list:
                log.debug("%s - %s - %s" % (repr(type(f)), repr(f), repr(os.path.isdir(f))))
                if os.path.isdir(f):
                    self.file_list.pop(self.file_list.index(f))
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(e.message)

    def exclude_files(self):
        for x in SETTINGS["excluded_files"]:
            for f in self.file_list:
                if f.endswith(x):
                    self.file_list.pop(self.file_list.index(f))

    def filtered_list(self):
        if not len(self.file_list):
            raise Exception("There is no file found.")
        log.info("{count} file{s} found".format(count=len(self.file_list),
                                                s='s' if len(self.file_list) > 1 else ''))
        return self.file_list
```

So my friends, what is your oppinions about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify the list which you iterate in this part of the code:

```
for f in self.file_list:
    log.debug("%s - %s - %s" % (repr(type(f)), repr(f), repr(os.path.isdir(f))))
    if os.path.isdir(f):
         self.file_list.pop(self.file_list.index(f))
```

Changing self.file_list while iterating it breaks the for loop.
You can either loop a copy of the list like this:

```
for f in self.file_list[:]:
```

or you have to move the changes out of the loop.

Comment: Holy moly! You're so right. I'm very angry to myself right now :)